# DriverManager unable to return connection after Java 8 upgrade

Tags: spring, jdbc, java-8

I have an application that tries to connect to Impala and Oracle. Below are the 2 beans defined.

Impala Driver - ImpalaJDBC41-2.5.41.jar
Oracle Driver - ojdbc6.jar

```
<bean id="ID1" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">

<property name="driverClassName" value="com.cloudera.impala.jdbc41.Driver"/>

<property name="url" value="jdbc:impala://impalahost:21050/;AuthMech=1;KrbRealm=myrealm;KrbServicName=impala;KrbHostFQDN=xxx" />

</bean>

<bean id="ID2" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
<property name="driverClassName" value="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver"/>
<property name="url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@//oraclehost:1523/DB" />
<property name="username" value="myuser" />
<property name="password" value="pwd" />
<property name="connectionProperties">
<props>
<prop key="defaultRowPrefetch">5000</prop>
</props>
</property>
</bean>
```

While getting the "Oracle" connection with a bean reference - ID2, getting this exception (surprisingly it goes to cloudera driver code)-

```
==java.lang.NullPointerException
===Stack trace...
java.util.Hashtable.put(Unknown Source)
com.cloudera.jdbc.common.AbstractDriver.copyProperties(Unknown Source)
com.cloudera.jdbc.common.AbstractDriver.connect(Unknown Source)
java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source)
java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(Unknown Source) org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFrom 
DriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:173) org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFrom 
Driver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:164) org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:149) org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:119) org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111) org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77)
```

The same configurations work fine with Java 1.7

Comment: Not related to your problem (or I'd be surprised if it was), but if you are using Java 8, why are you using ojdbc6 (which is for Java 6)? In any case, `java.sql.DriverManager` will iterate over all drivers to see which one will connect. Apparently the Impala driver is checked before the Oracle driver. This seems like a bug in the Impala driver. Check if there is a newer version available that fixes it.

Comment: I tried using the newer version for both the drivers; it doesn't help.

Comment: Then you should file a bug with Impala.

Comment: Surprisingly, it works fine with Java 1.7 with same settings.  If you check the exception; even if the application tries to connect to Oracle, the code flow enters into impala driver and fails there. I tried by renaming the impala jar to ZImpalaJDBC41-2.5.41.jar and all works fine. The Oracle driver is loaded before Impala. This looks like a bug in a way Java 1.8 handles both the drivers.

Comment: Given this is a null pointer exception inside Impala, I'd be surprised if this is a bug in `DriverManager`. Driver manager will poll each driver if it can connect using the provided JDBC url, if it can't it should return `null` (if the URL is not for the driver) or throw a `SQLException` (if the url is for the driver, but something is syntactically wrong, or the connection cannot be made). It sounds like Impala doesn't check if it can use the URL and then proceeds to process the URL which then fails because it is not an URL for Impala.

Comment: In any case, I notice that your Oracle definition has a property without a value (`<property name="connectionProperties">`), see what happens if you remove that or give it an explicit value (eg `value=""`). Given it happens in something called `copyProperties`, I wonder if this might be a problem with the fact `Hashtable.put` doesn't allow a `null` value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue occurs when Impala driver is loaded before the Oracle driver is loaded; since ImpalaJDBC41-2.5.41.jar is referred before ojdbc6.jar (alphabetic order). So I had 2 options to get the Oracle driver loaded first and both work fine -

1. rename Impala jar to ZImpala so that it gets referred after ojdbc jar
2. But the 'cleaner and better' approach was to load Oracle driver with custom module by configuring it as a JDBC Datasource inside Jboss standalone.xml; which will load Oracle driver even before our application EAR is deployed.